# Isogonal conjugates outside of a triangle

Tags: geometry

In $\bigtriangleup ABC$, let $M$ be an interior point and $S$ be a point outside the triangle such that $M, S$ are on different sides with respect to $BC$. It is given that $\angle ABM=\angle CBS, \angle ACM=\angle BCS$,prove that $\angle AMB+\angle CMS=180^{\circ}$.

It is pretty much the configuration of isogonal conjuagtes except that the points are outside,when they were inside it was pretty trivial to prove them through trig ceva,but don't know how to prove this configuration.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Could there be a connection with [Miquel points](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1604/1604.06995.pdf) ?

Answer (score 0):

Our answer is inspired by [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4175963) posted by @MathLover, in which a special case of the given geometric configuration was used to solve the general case. We use the properties of the special case illustrated in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$ to crack the general case.

$\underline{\mathrm{Note}}:\space$We extend the domain of $M$, which was originally limited to the interior of the $\triangle ABC$, so that it includes the side $BC$. This is necessary because in the considered special cases $M$ lies on $BC$.

Configuration shown in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$ was obtained by choosing $\measuredangle MCA = \measuredangle BCA$ and $\measuredangle ABM = \measuredangle ABC$ of the sketch given in the original post. It is easy to see that the point $S$ is the reflection of the vertex $A$ of the $\triangle ABC$ in its side $BC$. The two lines $CM$ and $BM$ coincide with the side $BC$ and, therefore, they can intersect at any point on $BC$. The point $M$ shown in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$ was selected arbitrarily. Now, this point must have properties similar to those of the point $M$ of the general case and that is exactly what we are going to prove right now.

[image: Special Case]

$\mathrm{\underline{Lemma}:\space A\space Special\space Case}$

In the geometric configuration given in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$, $\measuredangle BMA + \measuredangle CMS = 180^o$.

$\underline{\mathrm{Proof\space of\space the\space Lemma}}$

As mentioned above, $S$ is the reflection of $A$ in $BC$, Therefore,
$$\measuredangle AMC = \measuredangle CMS. \tag{1}$$

We know that $\measuredangle AMC$ and $\measuredangle BMA$  are supplementary. Therefore, according to (1), $\measuredangle CMS$ and $\measuredangle BMA$ are supplementary too, i.e.,
$$\measuredangle BMA + \measuredangle CNS = 180^o.$$

[image: General Case]

$\underline{\mathrm{Proof\space of\space General\space Case}}$

Consider the configuration shown in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 2}$, which was obtained by adding couple of constructions to the sketch given with the problem statement. For easy viewing, all added objects are shown in colors other than black. By the way, we do not have to worry about how these constructions are carried out. Instead, let us pay our attention to the new information they bring forth.

We call $ \measuredangle CMS$ the $\it{angle\space of\space interest}$ subtended at $M$ and denote it by $\phi$. Let $\measuredangle ABC$ equal $\omega$ for the sake of brevity.

In our first construction, we introduce $\triangle SCB_1$, which is inversely similar to $\triangle ABC$. The sides of $\triangle ABC$ are proportional to those of $\triangle SCB_1$ as given below.
$$ AB : BC :CA = SB_1 : B_1C : CS \tag{2}$$

We also have
$$ \measuredangle CB_1S = \measuredangle ABC = \omega \tag{3}$$

Please note that, according to this construction, the point $M$ lies on the side $CB_1$ of $\triangle SCB_1$, which corresponds to the side $BC$ of $\triangle ABC$. Hence, as far as the $\triangle SCB_1$ is concerned, $M$ depicts the special case studied in the lemma. The angle $CMS$, which is common to both triangles, is the angle of interest subtended at $M$. Let $\measuredangle B_1SM $ equal $\theta$.

It is given that $\measuredangle CBS = \measuredangle ABM $. Hence, we have
$$\measuredangle MBS= \measuredangle ABC = \omega.\tag{4}$$

Equations (3) and (4) show that $\measuredangle MBS= \measuredangle CB_1S = \omega$. This confirms that the quadrilateral $BSMB_1$ is cyclic. Therefore, we shall state,
$$ \measuredangle B_1BM = \measuredangle B_1SM = \theta. \tag{5}$$

Now, the configuration is extended further by adding the point $N$ on $BC$ to obtain the special case for $\triangle ABC$ as described in the lemma. However, we ensure that the angle of interest subtended at $N$, i.e. $\measuredangle CNT$, is equal to that subtended at $M$, i.e. $\phi$. By the way, $T$ is the reflection of $A$ in $BC$ (see the lemma). This construction makes the point $N$ of $\triangle ABC$ corresponds to the point $M$ of $\triangle SCB_1$.

We have already proven in the lemma that
$$ \measuredangle BNA = \measuredangle 180^o – CNT = 180^o - \phi. \tag{6}$$

Once we have $N$, we draw the three line segments $NA$, $NM$ and $BB_1$.

Since $N$ and $M$ are the apices of equal angles of interest of similar triangles $ABC$ and $SCB_1$ respectively, we shall write
$$BC : BN = B_1C : B_1M. \tag{7}$$

According to (7), the line segments $MN$ and $B_1B$ are parallel to each and they form the equal alternate angles $\measuredangle NMB$ and $\measuredangle B_1BM$. Therefore, from (5), we have
$$ \measuredangle NMB = \measuredangle B_1BM = \theta. \tag{8}$$

According to (2) and (7), we have
$$AB : BN = SB_1 : B_1M. \tag{9}$$

According to Euclid VI.6, the conditions (3) and (9) assure us that $\triangle SMB_1$ is inversely similar to $\triangle ABN$. Because of this, we have
$$\measuredangle NAB = \measuredangle B_1SM = \theta. \tag{10}$$

The condition $\measuredangle NAB = \measuredangle NMB$ follows from equations (8) and (10). This is necessary and sufficient for the quadrilateral $ABNM$ to be cyclic. Therefore, we have $\measuredangle BMA = \measuredangle BNA$, which, according to (6), can be written as $\measuredangle BMA =180^o - \phi$.

Finally, we shall state that
$$ \measuredangle CMS + \measuredangle BMA = \phi + 180^o - \phi = 180^0.$$